# Выбор значения с помощью JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть вот такой код, как при помощи Jquery выбрать значение с value=5, например?

```
    <a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">
       <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="1"> 
       <div class="dd-option-text">-12 Э</div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
       <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="2"> 
       <div class="dd-option-text">-24 Э</div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
       <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="3"> 
       <div class="dd-option-text">-36 Э</div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
       <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="4"> 
       <div class="dd-option-text">-48 Э</div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
       <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="5"> 
       <div class="dd-option-text">-60 Э</div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a class="dd-option">
       <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="6"> 
       <div class="dd-option-text">-72 Э</div>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через `each()`:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.dd-option-value').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 5) {
              alert($(this).next('.dd-option-text').text());
          }
       });
    });
```

Вот вам [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ox5sua3j/) и сразу с выводом значения ниже :)

**UPD.** Не совсем правильно понял автора, поэтому всё передел:

По клику теперь выбирается нужный элемент и выводится значение выбранного элемента.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dd-option').click(function() {
       $('.dd-option').removeClass('dd-option-selected');          
       $(this).addClass('dd-option-selected');
       alert($(this).find('.dd-option-value').val());
    });
});
```

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ox5sua3j/1/).

Comment: Только мне нужно не вывод сделать, а сделать это значение выбранным.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[value=5]")
```

Comment: Не-а, не работает.